# LinkedIn comment api not working, wrong path variables

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

The comments linkedIn api is not working like I would expect:

My code:

```
 $res = Http::withHeaders([
                    "LinkedIn-Version" => "202301",
                    "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" => "2.0.0",
                ])
                    ->withToken($post->account->bearer_token)
                    ->post(
                        sprintf(
                            env("LINKEDIN_API") . "socialActions/%s/comments",
                            $postId
                        ),
                        [
                            "actor" => $post->account->account_id,
                            "object" => $postId,
                            "message" => [
                                "text" => $post->linkedin_first_comment,
                            ],
                        ]
                    );
```

The url is this:

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:7037368272257712128/comments

Object id:

```
urn:li:share:7037368272257712128
```

But I keep receiving:

```
Syntax exception in path variables
```

What can be wrong here? Went through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api) lots of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use link:

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:CODE/comments

add header:

```
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer 'TOKEN,'LinkedIn-Version': "202209"}
```

Remove: `X-Restli-Protocol-Version`

Hope this helps.